# How to set middleware only specific page in Nuxt.js

Tags: javascript, jwt, frameworks, nuxt.js, middleware

In the `index`, `about-us`, and `contact-us` pages of my Nuxt app, I see this error:

```
GET http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/auth/user 401 (Unauthorized)
```

I installed `auth`, and use JWT from Laravel API. I want it to be used for the `dashboard`, `dashboard/user`, and `dashboard/post` pages only.

```
GET http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/auth/user
```

Comment: Can you provide more detailed code? maybe on codesandbox ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Page components can have their own middleware by setting the [`middleware` property](https://nuxtjs.org/docs/2.x/components-glossary/pages-middleware).

The Nuxt docs show this example for anonymous middleware:

```html
<template>
  <h1>Secret page</h1>
</template>

<script>
  export default {
    middleware({ store, redirect }) {
      // If the user is not authenticated
      if (!store.state.authenticated) {
        return redirect('/login')
      }
    }
  }
</script>
```

Comment: ok . but i error 401 in index page . index page not middleware set !:/

Comment: That sounds like a separate problem from the original question. Please post a new question with details on how to reproduce the issue.